# Server polling Angular js and get difference between the response

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an api getData method which returns json data every minute in angularjs.

```
function($scope, $http,$timeout, confirm) {

  (function tick() {
     $http.get('myapi.json').success(function(data) {

        $scope.operation =  data ;

            $timeout(tick, 60000);

         })
    })();
```

JSON DATA looks like this. 
               [{ "requests" :"200"} ....]
After every minute the "requests" value changes. I want to find the difference between the previous request value and current  request value. I tried $scope.$watch but doesn't give the object value change. Please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: when you tried $scope.$watch, did you set the 3rd parameter to `true`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. Now I am trying to have a global scope prevData and store previous value in that using angular.copy($scope.operation, $scope.prevData);

Comment: But it returns Object {length: 0}  instead of any data

Comment: you should post more code